# MongoDB E11000 dup key on insertMany but not on insertOne on empty collection with default index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

**Error description**

I write a node.js application with TypeScript using MongoDB (npm mongodb).

On writing an array of objs with

```
await collection.insertMany(objs)
```

to a collection the error

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: CollectionName index: _id_ dup
> key {_id: ObjectId('60c5d8170f845073
> 5882376a')}"

is thrown.
No error is thrown on iterating over all objects and inserting them one by one:

```
for (const obj of objs) {
    await collection.insertOne(obj)
}
```

I have not specified any indexes manually therefore the default index generated by MongoDB should be used.
The collection is empty/non existent on insertMany-call.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried deleting all _id-fields before writing to the database.

   ```
    for (const obj of objs) {
        delete obj["_id"] 
    }
    await collection.insertMany(objs)
   ```
2. I have dropped the DB with MongoCompass

**Question**
How is it possible that this error is thrown?

Comment: Make sure that there aren't any duplicate keys within the objects you are trying to bulk insert. Check mainly your `_id` and other keys with `unique-indexes`

Comment: Aside from the dup key problem, consider a insertMany using the unordered option (multithread approach - must faster).

Comment: What is content of  `objs` you trying to insert?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the collection and run your query again it worked for me